# REST API: PUT but no need all data in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my controller to update put user data. The controller accepts up to 4 values. I would like to do so if I send only a name to this route, This will change only the name and the rest will remain unchanged. (it will not be empty). Is it possible to do this? Do I have to do it in redux-saga, i.e. if it is empty, give it up-to-date

```
// Update basic User's Data
exports.setUserdata = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.userId;
  User.update(
    {
      password: req.body.password,
      name: req.body.name,
      surname: req.body.surname,
      email: req.body.email,
    },
    { where: { id } },
  )
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    });
};
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @KyawKyawSoe, MySQL

Comment: please provide more detail, such as how you implemented `User.update()`, how your input (`params`) data will look like.

Comment: Did you store the password in plain text?!

Comment: @Marc, no. I have only name and surname in the Redux store, haha :)

Comment: According to the REST constraints, PUT isn't the right HTTP method is you want to perform a partial update. You should rather use PATCH. See https://medium.com/qudini-engineering/94fd92a0e6d4#3adc, section "How to partially update a resource?", as well as the linked article, https://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/.

Answer (score 0):

Pass params you want to update and don't pass other keys.

If `req.body` contains only `name` key, you can just pick up those 4 keys from `req.body`.

```
const updateParams = _.pick(req.body, ['name', 'password', 'surname', 'email'])
User.update(updateParams, {  where: { id } })
```

If `req.body` has other properties with value `null` or `undefined`, you can filter them after picking.

```
const updateParams = _.chain(req.body).pick(['name', 'password', 'surname', 'email']).filter().value()
User.update(updateParams, {  where: { id } })
```

Of course it depends on the ORM you are using but I believe most ORM don't update attributes which are not passed at all.